# NEXUS eligibility after moving out of the US

Tags: nexus, canadian-residents

**Context**:
I am a Canadian PR living in Canada (not a North American citizen). I had applied for and received NEXUS membership when I was in the US and had a valid US visa. I satisfied the eligibility requirement then since I met the 3 year residency requirement (in US) and I was a Canadian PR at the time.

Now my US visa expired and I have moved to Canada since, I no longer visit US and have never got a chance to use my NEXUS card for entry for one reason or another. Note that there's no way to update visa information on the Trusted Traveler Program website.

Note the NEXUS eligibility criteria here: https://travel.gc.ca/travelling/documents/nexus
and
https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/application-demande-eng.html

Based on this am I right to think that I still remain eligible to possess the NEXUS card?
Neither of those links explicitly state that changes in visa status of one country (either US or Canada) makes me ineligible (of course, as long as I am a citizen or PR of the other country which I am)

Assuming that I am still eligible for the NEXUS membership, this brings me to my next question. If I receive a US visa, e.g. a tourist visa, am I required to report to a NEXUS enrollment center in Canada (or US), either separately, or when I am traveling there? Getting a US visa still hasn't negatively affected my eligibility.

And lastly, in my current situation (Canadian PR, no US visa, valid NEXUS card), can I use NEXUS card processing if I am entering Canada (or any other country that accepts NEXUS cards on their kiosks), for a faster entry?

Answer (score 1):

If your Nexus card has not expired, you must update your personal info online(address, driver's licence, phone etc) and go to the nearest Nexus enrollment center to give them any new documents that you have, so that they can scan them and upload them to their system and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already updated the license, address and other information online on Trusted Traveler Program. I don't yet have any other new  immigration-related documents (new US visa etc.). Can I wait if/till I get a new US visa (e.g. a tourist visa) and then report to a Nexus enrollment center?
Based on the description in link regarding NEXUS eligibility, I don't think I have lost any eligibility as a reason of the expired US visa.

Comment: Technically, getting a Canadian PR falls under the:"Changes to permanent resident card information" that you *must* physically go to an enrollment center for: https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/contact-coordonnees-eng.html .If it's not too far and to not risk getting rejected when you have to go there to show them your visa, I'd recommend dropping by a Nexus office. But be aware: the US and Canadian systems aren't linked, you may not have noticed since they are behind a desk, but they first enter your info on a Canadian computer and then repeat that on a special "American" laptop.

Comment: And visa-versa. Not all Canadian centers have that American laptop. e.g. in Vancouver, the main downtown office has it, but the airport one doesn't(they need a CBP/CBSA officer from the other side on site to have one)

Comment: I already have a Canadian PR (Which is why I could apply for a Nexus card). The only thing that changed is I moved to Canada, and my US Visa is no longer valid (which should not be an issue wrt eligibility since that is based on my Canadian status)